# Why can't I extend /home partition using Gparted?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted

Here's the screenshot:

[image: gparted]

`sda7` is `/home` partition in my case. I want to extend it using unallocated space of 95+GB, but I can't seem to do that.

Comment: To grow a partition, the free space must be *next-to* the partition you are going to re-size. Thus you'll need to move partition sda4, which may have effects depending on how sda4 is utilized (*particularly if it's used in a windows boot process*)

Comment: @guiverc Gparted was too much hassle. I gave up & assigned the the unallocated free space to /home & unmounted the old home. Thanks anyway!